# How to create Bookmarklet for my website which requires user authentication

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bookmarklet, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to create a bookmarklet for my website. I just want to do same as [Readitlater](http://readitlaterlist.com/) or as  [delicious](http://delicious.com/). 
Whenever you click on **Read It Later** or **save on delicious** bookmarklet if user is  not logged in, it asks user to login to continue & then save the bookmark. Otherwise if user is  logged in then it  directly saves the bookmark for user.

I want to implement exactly the same in my website & I am working on Ruby on Rails platform.
I have following javascript code for bookmarklet

```
<a href="javascript:u=document.location.href;t=document.title; s=window.getSelection();
void(window.open('http://www.example.com/node/add/web2ob?edit[title]='+escape(t)+
'&edit[body_field][body]='+escape(s)+'&edit[field_link][0][url]='+escape(u),
'_blank','width=600,height=500,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'));">
Add to my list</a>
```

I am new to this stuff so please guide me.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this question?

Answer (score -1):

You have to check if the user is connected, if he is then just put your link, else, put another link which will pop up an authentication form and if he successfully sign in you'll execute your js code. 
Like following: (I assume you're in a rails view, so in a html.erb file)

```
<% if user_signed_in? %> 
  <a href="javascript:u=document.location.href;t=document.title; s=window.getSelection();
void(window.open('http://www.example.com/node/add/web2ob?edit[title]='+escape(t)+
'&edit[body_field][body]='+escape(s)+'&edit[field_link][0][url]='+escape(u),
'_blank','width=600,height=500,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'));">
Add to my list</a>
<% else %>
  <a onclick="showLoginForm();">Add to my list</a>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am not sure if your answer is what he is looking for. When you are on a different domain (other than your Rails app), you have no easy way of checking if the user is logged in to your Rails app.